# Ionic Content scrollTo strange behavior

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I have a strange problem with two pages that had same content. I have a list that contains a Ionic2-Calendar and then some dynamic items with "events" of the calendar (not the list of events of Ionic2-Calendar).

```
---------------------------------------
CALENDAR
Day 1
Day n
---------------------------------------
Dynamic item 1
...
Dynamic item n
---------------------------------------
```

The idea is that when you click a day with an event on the calendar, the app scrolls to the first event of this day. This works.

This is how I do the scroll. I assign the Id of the Event (returned from server) to the ion-item.

```
<ion-item class="dataView" *ngFor="let result of json.Events" [id]="result.Id" (click)="editClass(result)">
```

This is my ts:

```
export class CalendartestPage {

@ViewChild(Content) contentDetails: Content;

...

// Here we detect the click on the calendar and then,
// if there's events we do the scroll
onTimeSelected(ev) {
  if ( ev.events.length > 0 ) {
// Here we get the Id of the event
    this.scrollToEvent( ev.events[0].event_id );
  }
}

// Here we do the scroll to the content element, I repeat, this works
scrollToEvent(event) {
    let yOffset = document.getElementById( event ).offsetTop;
    console.error("\t\t\tscrollToEvent details --> "+ yOffset );
    this.contentDetails.scrollTo(0, yOffset, 1500);
  }

...

}
```

Ok, so where is the problem? This app uses tabs. One of those two pages is in one of the tabs, and the other one is modal.

If I open the modal first, the scrollTo works perfectly. But if I go first to the tabbed page (here the scrollTo works) and then to the modal one, the scrollTo does not scroll to the item. I don't know why, but the **offsetTop** of the selected element has value 0, so app scrolls to top, and this only happens when you go to the tabbed page first.

How do you think I can solve this? Maybe I have to remove something of the tabbed page when it loses focus?

Comment: Could you make it easier for us by providing a [https://stackblitz.com/](https://stackblitz.com/)

Comment: I tested it in stackblitz, but the scrollTo is not working on browser :/